# convert text file column into csv file single row using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, txt

I have text file which look like this:
[txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4PfX.png)

Now I want to convert that text file in csv file single row

The outcome would look like:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ij6k.png)

This is my code:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as fin,\
     open("file.csv", "w") as fout:
    col1, col2,col3,col4 = zip(*(line.rstrip().split() for line in fin))
    fout.write(",".join(col1 + col2 +col4 +col5))
```

textfile:

```html
data1   data5  data9   data13
data2          data10  data14
data    data7  data11  data15
data4          data12  data16

1       5      9      13
2              10     14  
3       7      11     15 
4              12     16

output:
data1 data2 data3 data4 data5     data7     data10 data11 .... data16
1      2     3    4      5         7           10   11    ....   16
```

Comment: can you share the input and output in text so we can reproduce the behaviour? The first thing I can say is that in your code, you are not reading the file (fin.read() or fin.readlines()).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach:

1. Use a regular expression to pick out all the entries.
2. Split the list in two and sort the pairs based on the numeric value found in each 'header' value. Conversion to integer is needed to avoid `data10` being sorted before `data1`.
3. Build a list of the sorted key value pairs.
4. Use a `csv.writer()` to create the CSV file by transposing the entries into two rows.

For example:

```py
import re
import csv

with open('file.txt') as f_input:
    data = re.findall('\w+', f_input.read())
    items = len(data) // 2

with open('file.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:    
    kv = [(k, v) for k, v in sorted(zip(data[:items], data[items:]), key=lambda x: int(re.search('\d+', x[0]).group(0)))]
    csv.writer(f_output).writerows(zip(*kv))
```

Giving you `file.csv` containing:

```
data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data7,data9,data10,data11,data12,data13,data14,data15,data16
1,2,3,4,5,7,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16
```